# No puedo enviar emails con symfony en producción

Tags: php, symfony2

Tengo una aplicación en produccíon que cuando intenta enviar un email me da este error " Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "no-response@card2card.es" using 2 possible authenticators".

La configuración es la siguiente:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: send.one.com
mailer_user: no-response@card2card.es
mailer_password: no-response361
```

En mi servidor local funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¿Usas la misma autenticación desde tu servidor local?

Comment: Si, es exactamente la misma.